# Magento Transactional email template header and footer not loading

Tags: magento-1.9, template, email, transactional-mail

In Magento 1.9.1 the email setup/building process was changed and the email templates are responsive.

In my case, my template email was not working, it was neither loading header nor footer, just appears that:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}} 
{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

Then I updated my Magento store and it was working, but appeared many bugs in my Magento store so I replaced some updated folders and files with some old ones, then my Magento store worked again but the email template didn't load the header and footer, somebody knows what it can be?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

you need to change mail header template form 
System > configuration > design > Transnational Emails

Comment: Is that only in Enterprise Edition of Magento 1.9? I don't see the `Email Header Template` or `Email Footer Template` fields in Community Edition Magento 1.9.

Comment: Just checked its available for both Magento CE and EE. But is only available in 1.9.1 .. i am using 1.9.0.1.